# Compressing and decompress data through sockets

Tags: java, sockets, server, compression

I'm having issues with this question right now.
For this question, I have to:

Client side: compress each input line from the console, send it to the server and decompress each message from server

Server side: decompress data from client, change the lower-case letters to upper case, compress it and send back to the client

The best I can do is do everything above with only ONE line.

Client Side:

```
/* SOCKET CONNECTING STUFF UP HERE */

    /*PROBLEMS START AROUND HERE */
    String line;
    BufferedReader bis = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    DeflaterOutputStream compress = new DeflaterOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream(), true);


    InflaterInputStream decompress = new InflaterInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    BufferedReader fromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(decompress));

    line = bis.readLine();

    line = line + "\n";
    compress.write(line.getBytes(), 0, line.length());
    compress.finish();
    System.out.println("Message sent: " + line);
    System.out.println("Message Returned : " +fromClient.readLine());

    /* closing the streams here */
    bis.close();
    decompress.close();
    compress.close();
    fromClient.close();
    socket.close();
}

}
```

Server Side:

```
String line = "";
    OutputStream outstream = new FileOutputStream("compessserver.txt");

    InflaterInputStream decompress = new InflaterInputStream(clientsocket.getInputStream());
    BufferedReader fromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(decompress));
    DeflaterOutputStream compress = new DeflaterOutputStream(clientsocket.getOutputStream());

    while ((line = fromClient.readLine()) != null) {
        String upperLine = line.toUpperCase();
        System.out.println("Message received and converted: " + upperLine);
        System.out.println();
        upperLine = upperLine + "\n";
        byte[] input = upperLine.getBytes();
        outstream.write(input);
        outstream.write("\r\n".getBytes());
        compress.write(input);
        System.out.println("Message returned : " + upperLine);
        compress.finish();
        if (upperLine.equalsIgnoreCase("x")) {
            break;
        }

    }

    decompress.close();
    compress.close();
    fromClient.close();
    outstream.close();
    socket.close();
}
}
```

I really need help in this please. If I try to make this multiple inputs instead, the whole code just messes up. Been at this for days.

EDIT: Forgot to mention this. What I'm supposed to do is input a line, compress it, send to server, server decompress it and upper case letters, compress it, send back to client. And then I supposed to input more lines until I put in a single letter like "Q" which in case, ends the program

I tried the following code to make it work for multiple lines

Second Try Client Side:

```
    String line;
    BufferedReader bis = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    DeflaterOutputStream compress = new DeflaterOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream(), true);


    InflaterInputStream decompress = new InflaterInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    BufferedReader fromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(decompress));
    line = bis.readLine();
    while ((!line.equalsIgnoreCase("x"))) {
        compress.write(line.getBytes(), 0, line.length());
        System.out.println("Message sent: " + line);
        System.out.println("Message returned:" +fromClient.readLine() );
        line = bis.readLine();
    }

    bis.close();
    fromClient.close();
    socket.close();
}
```

}

Second Try Server Side:

```
OutputStream outstream = new FileOutputStream("compessserver.txt");
    InflaterInputStream decompress = new InflaterInputStream(clientsocket.getInputStream());
    BufferedReader fromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(decompress));
    DeflaterOutputStream compress = new DeflaterOutputStream(clientsocket.getOutputStream());

    while ((line = fromClient.readLine()) != null) {
        String upperLine = line.toUpperCase();
        System.out.println("Message received and converted: " + upperLine);
        System.out.println();
        upperLine = upperLine + "\n";
        byte[] input = upperLine.getBytes();
        outstream.write(input);
        outstream.write("\r\n".getBytes());
        compress.write(input);
        System.out.println("Message returned : " + upperLine);

        if (upperLine.equalsIgnoreCase("x")) {
            break;
        }

    }

    decompress.close();
    fromClient.close();
    outstream.close();
    socket.close();
}
```

}

Comment: What is the issue? What are you expecting to happen? What happens instead?

Comment: Well, I can only get it to work if I input a single line on the console. What I'm supposed to do is input a line, compress it, send to server, server decompress it  and upper case letters, compress it, send back to client. And then I supposed to input more lines until I put in a single letter like "Q"

Comment: What happens when you try with two lines? Is it that you type something, press enter, the request is run, the server returns the appropriate response, then the client program ends? Can you point out the line of code that you think should cause the program to ask for a second line?

Comment: @JohnC The code I posted only works with one line then it ends. Another code I'm working on (and it's seriously messed up and full of errors) is that when I input one line, the write function (client side) won't send it until I put "Q". But then the server won't be able to process it and comes out with an error.

Comment: Yes, in the client code above, I see no loop. If you were to remove all of the code from the client dealing with the server, would it ask you for another line over and over again until you typed "Q"?

Comment: @JohnC Not for this code, no. The other code, yes. Should I post that one instead? Can I still post it around this question/thread?

Comment: Yes, I think you can still edit your post. Just add it as "Client Try 2" so we can see everything you've tried. I think that would be a good next step for helping you figure this out. It seems the answer is probably a combination of these two excerpts.

Comment: Ok, I just edited my post to show the second code

Comment: `compress.write(line.getBytes(), 0, line.length())` isn't valid. It should be `compress.write(line.getBytes(), 0, line.getBytes().length())`, or more simply `compress.write(line.getBytes())`.

Comment: @EJP I tried that but its the same thing. compress.write() wont send the line until i press "X", in which case, comes out with error in the server side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use these streams interactively. You would have to call `finish()` after every write, or rather before every read, which means you could only do one write. They are designed for large one-way streams, not interactive request/response sessions.

In any case there is no advantage to be gained from compressing single lines. You need a lot of data for compression to start working.

NB `compress.write(line.getBytes(), 0, line.length())` isn't valid. It assumes the number of chars in the `String` is the same as the number of bytes when converted, which isn't always so. It should be `compress.write(line.getBytes(), 0, line.getBytes().length())`, or more simply `compress.write(line.getBytes())`.

Comment: So, in this case, is it best to put the input lines into a text file first, compress that and send it over to server? DeflaterOutputStream is just fine, right?

Comment: @BeyondDays `DeflaterOutputStream` would be a better option. Writing a text file is certainly futile; writing a compressed file and then sending it adds a lot of latency you don't need.